# What is the best way to use C++ Protobuf Arena for Repeated fields?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am having the following protobuf:

```
message Message {
...
}

message Response {
  repeated Message messages = 0;
}

service MessageService {
  GetMessage() return (Reponse);
}
```

And in my C++ code, I am doing some message computation on-fly and want to add the message in to `messages` field. I am doing:

```
Arena arena;
// some iteration loop
for {
  auto message =
      google::protobuf::Arena::CreateMessage<Message>(arena);
  response->mutable_messages()->AddAllocated(message);
}
```

The total size of messages is large, so I think using Arena would be more performant.
But it seems that `AddAllocated` would copy the Arena (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.repeated_field#RepeatedPtrField.AddAllocated.details), because `messages` field is not from Arena.

What is the best way of doing this? Should I use Arena?

Comment: It depends entirely on if the `response` proto uses the same arena. Is that in the same arena? The documentation is clear about what happens in any case, so I don't understand the question.

Comment: @MooingDuck response is passed from the grpc server generated code `grpc::Status MessageServiceImpl::GetMessages(
    grpc::ServerContext* context,
    const GetMessageRequest* request,
    GetMessageResponse* response)`, so I have no control of where response is created.. That is why I am wondering if Arena is not designed for such usecase.

Comment: I've never seen C++ protobuffers before, but it looks like the answer is just `Arena* arena = response->mutable_messages()->GetArena()`?

Comment: Thx! I realize I was using an older version of the code